# trudging down the street

Tags: word-usage

> It is raining, and they are trudging down the street.

In dictionary trudge defined as "To walk in a laborious, heavy-footed way".
So when it's raining, and the person walk quickly and laboriously, can I use the word "trudging"?

Comment: You may certainly say *They are trudging down the street* even if it is not raining! :)  Quite seriously, what role does *it is raining* play in your question?

Comment: @StoneyB Since it's raining, they walk quickly and laboriously.

Comment: Ah, I missed *quickly*. *Trudging* is slow. *Lumber*, *lurch*, *wallow*, *scuttle*, or *galumph* might be what you're looking for. Only *scuttle* includes the notion of speed, but the others do not EXclude speed.

Comment: @StoneyB: Also "*slog*", which indicates difficulty and exertion, but does not preclude speed.

Comment: @StoneyB, "quick" and "laborious" seem like mutually exclusive options to me...

Comment: As others have mentioned, it wouldn't make sense to say *trudged quickly*

Comment: @Hellion Me too; so I thought of myself as a kid trying to run home through shin-deep Alabama red-clay mud in a rainstorm.

Comment: I have come to share @Hellion's observation that "quick" and "laborious" are mutually exclusive. Accordingly, I am voting to close this as Not A Real Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some of the commenters noted, *trudging* implies moving along at a very slow, laborious pace, picking up one foot and placing it in front of the other, over and over and over again. It implies there is resistance or some sort of fatigue.

If you are wanting to say that the people walking in the rain were trying to move along quickly to get inside as soon as possible, you might use the word [*scurry*, which means](http://www.wordnik.com/words/scurry):

> To hurry along; move hastily and precipitately; scamper.
>
> *It is raining, and they are scurrying down the street.*

If you are wanting to say that the people walking in the rain were actually hindered by the rain or the wet street conditions, you could correctly use the word [*trudge*, which means](http://www.wordnik.com/words/trudge):

> To walk in a laborious, heavy-footed way; plod.
>
> *It is raining, and they are trudging through the puddles and mud down the street.*

Note, however, that the mental image that accompanies the last sentence is not one of people moving quickly.